# jquery ui css not working offline

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, accordion

I am using JQuery UI Accordion, which is working perfect with online imports of

> jquery-ui.css, jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery-ui.js

but, if I use my downloaded files in imports, then jquery.ui.css is not working.

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Monitoring</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var icons = {
                header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
                activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
            };
            $('#acc_main').accordion({
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
            $("#acc_child").accordion({
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                heightStyle: "content",
                icons: icons
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        h3{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="acc_main">
        <h3>Main Section</h3>
        <div id="acc_child">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <div>
                1st section
            </div>
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <div>
                2nd section
            </div>
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <div>
                List : 
                <ul>
                    <li>List item one</li>
                    <li>List item two</li>
                    <li>List item three</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My output with local imports:

[image: Output]

My Project hierarchy:

[image: Project]

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: yes, error 404 for some images not available, like: ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png, ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png etc.

Comment: please open your development tools/resources/frames/.. and make sure your js files and css are loaded

Comment: Beside checking the obvious as already mentioned, make sure that the file are readable by your webserver (`chmod 644`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Yashhy, I have downloaded images of a ***custom JQuery UI Theme***, so icon images are not displaying.
But now I have ***downloaded images from stable JQuery UI Theme*** and my problem has been solved.

Comment: even having the online link just for css will not even require downloading images.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the path to your css files is not correct.
Try to replace href="css/jquery-ui.css" by href="/css/jquery-ui.css"

The slash at the begin means that the folder is found at the root, without slash means that the css folder is relative to the current page